# Scalar Product Conditions

Tags: complex-analysis, mathematical-physics, vector-analysis

Let $x$ and $y$ be two vectors, $x\cdot y$ their scalar product, $\beta$ the angle between the vectors, and $|x|$ and $|y|$ their absolute values. Then we have

$$|x| |y| \cos \beta =x \cdot y \quad     (1)$$

I wonder for what precise conditions when (1) implies

$$\cos \beta =\frac{x\cdot y}{|x| |y|} \quad     (2)$$

Thanks

Comment: $|x|\neq0,|y|\neq0$?

Comment: Yes,  
|x|≠0,|y|≠0 , we must keep in mind this. So for what precise condition...

Comment: So (2) is simply algebraic deduction from (1)

Comment: Yes, I knew this its simple algebraic deduction of (1), what I wounder is condition, there should be some condition for which (1) implies (2).

Comment: Like what? What do you think?

Comment: First I was thinking the same condition, like,  
|x|≠0,|y|≠0, and then I wrote, simply algebraic deduction of (1). But my teacher said no, there is something else, think. I tried to find it but unfortunately I could not find anything that is suitable or convening.

Comment: Perhaps your instructor is looking for a condition on $x$ itself?  If $|x|=0$, what does $x$ have to be?

Comment: No other condition in fact

Answer (score 1):

First one has to ask: What is an angle as geometric object?

Then, this identity is the definition of the angle measure $β$ for given nonzero vectors $x$ and $y$.

The deep insight behind it is the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, or the Binet-Cauchy equation if you want a term for the difference in the CS inequality. This tells you that $|x⋅y|\le |x||y|$ so that the fraction $\frac{x⋅y}{|x||y|}$ actually takes values inside the intervall $[-1,1]$ so that it can be identified with values of the cosine function.